# Forbidding keywords in listings

Tags: listings

I would like to force the `listings` package to be more selective when highlighting keywords. I'm currently including C source files in my document, and while I'm happy that occurrences of the **float** keyword are properly highlighted, I'd like the following line to appear as

`#include <float.h>`

instead of the current

`#include <`**float**`.h>`

In a similar spirit, **else** is fine, but `#else` should be typeset instead of #**else**.

I tried solutions like using `deletekeywords={float.}`, but to no avail (unsurprisingly, according to the documentation: "(...) by default some characters are not allowed inside
keywords, for example ‘-’, ‘:’, ‘.’, and so on. (...)"). Playing with `deletedirectives` led nowhere either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keyword is `float` without dot, not `float.`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, deletekeywords={float}]
#include <float.h>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

It is more difficult to have both. The `literate` feature seems to do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  language=C,
  literate={float.}{float.}6,
]
#include <float.h>
float a = 1.0;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If you do not want a special formatting of directives, it can be disabled by an empty `directivestyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
  language=C,
  directivestyle={},
  literate={float.}{float.}6,
  columns=flexible,
]
#include <float.h>
float a = 1.0;
#ifdef foo
#else
#endif
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: "The keyword is float without dot, not float. (...)": yes, but the one with the dot was the one I wanted to remove. Other than that, the literate trick works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem turned out to be subtle.

```
\lstset{
    language=C,
    directivestyle=\color[HTML]{006E28},
    deletedelim=*[directive]\#,
    moredelim=[directive][directivestyle]\#,
}
```

From the listings manual:

`moredelim=[\*[*]] [<type>] [[<style>]]<delimiter(s)>`

If you use one optional star, the package will detect keywords, comments,
and strings inside the delimited code. With both optional stars, aditionally
the style is applied cumulatively;