# Avoid highlighting keywords following certain words in listings

Tags: listings, code

`instance` and `of` are keywords in Haskell. But they also appear in error messages like `No instance for... arising from the use of...`. I'd like to tell `listings` that `instance` after `No` shouldn't be considered a keyword (while not removing highlighting entirely). Is it possible?

Based on [Forbidding keywords in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114251/forbidding-keywords-in-listings), I hoped

```
literate={use of}{use of}6
```

would do the trick, but it doesn't (weirdly, giving 11 as the length for `No instance` produces "Improper alphabetic constant" and "Missing number, treated as zero").

Example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=Haskell,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    literate={use of}{use of}6
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
<interactive>:11:1: error:
No instance for (Num Bool) arising from a use of '+'
In the expression: True + False
In an equation for 'it': it = True + False
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The desired result is that `Num`, `Bool`, `True` and `False` are still highlighted, but `instance` and `of` shouldn't be (preferably without changing contents of `lstlisting` environment).

Comment: Always add a complete example. That makes it much easier to test and analyze a problem.

Comment: I don't know for sure and since you don't show complete code can't really tell, but perhaps you have to group the `11` to `{11}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry again, fixed.

Comment: @CarLaTeX This is an answer to the "weirdly..." side note, but not to the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was.