# Is there a way to find all Cyrillic typewriter fonts on CTAN?

Tags: fonts, typewriter, cyrillic

DejaVu and Droid both provide good T2A typewriter fonts. I wanted to check if there are alternatives, but couldn't find a good way to do so using either http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue, CTAN, or MikTeX Console.

Example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}

\lstset{
    language=Haskell,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    escapeinside=!!,
    tabsize=4,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    keepspaces=true
}
\lstset{
    literate={а}{{\selectfont\char224}}1
    {б}{{\selectfont\char225}}1
    {в}{{\selectfont\char226}}1
    {г}{{\selectfont\char227}}1
    {д}{{\selectfont\char228}}1
    {е}{{\selectfont\char229}}1
    {ё}{{\"e}}1
    {ж}{{\selectfont\char230}}1
    {з}{{\selectfont\char231}}1
    {и}{{\selectfont\char232}}1
    {й}{{\selectfont\char233}}1
    {к}{{\selectfont\char234}}1
    {л}{{\selectfont\char235}}1
    {м}{{\selectfont\char236}}1
    {н}{{\selectfont\char237}}1
    {о}{{\selectfont\char238}}1
    {п}{{\selectfont\char239}}1
    {р}{{\selectfont\char240}}1
    {с}{{\selectfont\char241}}1
    {т}{{\selectfont\char242}}1
    {у}{{\selectfont\char243}}1
    {ф}{{\selectfont\char244}}1
    {х}{{\selectfont\char245}}1
    {ц}{{\selectfont\char246}}1
    {ч}{{\selectfont\char247}}1
    {ш}{{\selectfont\char248}}1
    {щ}{{\selectfont\char249}}1
    {ъ}{{\selectfont\char250}}1
    {ы}{{\selectfont\char251}}1
    {ь}{{\selectfont\char252}}1
    {э}{{\selectfont\char253}}1
    {ю}{{\selectfont\char254}}1
    {я}{{\selectfont\char255}}1
    {А}{{\selectfont\char192}}1
    {Б}{{\selectfont\char193}}1
    {В}{{\selectfont\char194}}1
    {Г}{{\selectfont\char195}}1
    {Д}{{\selectfont\char196}}1
    {Е}{{\selectfont\char197}}1
    {Ё}{{\"E}}1
    {Ж}{{\selectfont\char198}}1
    {З}{{\selectfont\char199}}1
    {И}{{\selectfont\char200}}1
    {Й}{{\selectfont\char201}}1
    {К}{{\selectfont\char202}}1
    {Л}{{\selectfont\char203}}1
    {М}{{\selectfont\char204}}1
    {Н}{{\selectfont\char205}}1
    {О}{{\selectfont\char206}}1
    {П}{{\selectfont\char207}}1
    {Р}{{\selectfont\char208}}1
    {С}{{\selectfont\char209}}1
    {Т}{{\selectfont\char210}}1
    {У}{{\selectfont\char211}}1
    {Ф}{{\selectfont\char212}}1
    {Х}{{\selectfont\char213}}1
    {Ц}{{\selectfont\char214}}1
    {Ч}{{\selectfont\char215}}1
    {Ш}{{\selectfont\char216}}1
    {Щ}{{\selectfont\char217}}1
    {Ъ}{{\selectfont\char218}}1
    {Ы}{{\selectfont\char219}}1
    {Ь}{{\selectfont\char220}}1
    {Э}{{\selectfont\char221}}1
    {Ю}{{\selectfont\char222}}1
    {Я}{{\selectfont\char223}}1
}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\itshape,
    keywordstyle= % TODO https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415777/avoid-highlighting-keywords-following-certain-words-in-listings
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinline|АБВ|
\end{document}
```

Comment: Look here maybe, which, however, lists *all* cyrillic fonts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/what-fonts-are-compatible-with-t2a-cyrillic-encoding

Comment: It seems to be missing DejaVu, which is a big one (commented there).

Comment: You should be aware of XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX that actually supports using any font you want via the `fontspec` package. Here, some more fonts are shipped with the TeX distributions that, however, cannot easily be used with PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to compile my existing document with them gives a lot of errors. I'll need to figure out the necessary changes later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends with what you want to compile your document. For PDFLaTeX, the following is valid:

I just searched my TeX distribution (TeX Live 2017) for files with names starting with `t2a` or `T2A` and ending with `.fd` and got the following list:

```
t2aantt.fd
t2aanttc.fd
t2aanttl.fd
t2aanttlc.fd
t2accr.fd
t2acmbr.fd
t2acmdh.fd
t2acmfib.fd
t2acmfr.fd
t2acmr.fd
t2acmss.fd
t2acmtl.fd
t2acmtt.fd
t2acmvtt.fd
t2afca.fd
t2afcm.fd
t2afco.fd
t2afcs.fd
t2afct.fd
t2afdm.fd
t2afdr.fd
t2afds.fd
T2Afla.fd
t2afmm.fd
t2afos.fd
t2afosj.fd
t2agentium.fd
t2aiwona.fd
t2aiwonac.fd
t2aiwonal.fd
t2aiwonalc.fd
t2akurier.fd
t2akurierc.fd
t2akurierl.fd
t2akurierlc.fd
t2alcmss.fd
t2alcmtt.fd
t2atempora-tlf.fd
t2atempora-tosf.fd
T2ACochineal-LF.fd
T2ACochineal-OsF.fd
T2ACochineal-Sup.fd
T2ACochineal-TLF.fd
T2ACochineal-TOsF.fd
T2ADejaVuSans-TLF.fd
T2ADejaVuSansCondensed-TLF.fd
T2ADejaVuSansMono-TLF.fd
T2ADejaVuSerif-TLF.fd
T2ADejaVuSerifCondensed-TLF.fd
T2Aerewhon-Dnom.fd
T2Aerewhon-Inf.fd
T2Aerewhon-LF.fd
T2Aerewhon-Numr.fd
T2Aerewhon-OsF.fd
T2Aerewhon-Sup.fd
T2Aerewhon-TLF.fd
T2Aerewhon-TOsF.fd
T2AHeuristica-Inf.fd
T2AHeuristica-Sup.fd
T2AHeuristica-TLF.fd
T2AHeuristica-TOsF.fd
T2ALinuxLibertineT-LF.fd
T2ALinuxLibertineT-OsF.fd
T2ALinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd
T2ALinuxLibertineT-TOsF.fd
T2ANimbusMono.fd
T2ANimbusMonoN.fd
T2ANimbusSans.fd
T2ANimbusSerif.fd
T2APTMono-TLF.fd
T2APTSans-TLF.fd
T2APTSansCaption-TLF.fd
T2APTSansNarrow-TLF.fd
T2APTSerif-TLF.fd
T2APTSerifCaption-TLF.fd
T2Alato-LF.fd
T2Alato-OsF.fd
T2Alato-TLF.fd
T2Alato-TOsF.fd
T2AXCharter-Sup.fd
T2AXCharter-TLF.fd
T2AXCharter-TOsF.fd
```

Of these, the following are monospaced fonts:

```
t2acmtl.fd
t2acmtt.fd
t2afct.fd
t2afdm.fd
t2alcmtt.fd
T2ADejaVuSansMono-TLF.fd
T2ANimbusMono.fd
T2ANimbusMonoN.fd
T2APTMono-TLF.fd
```

But then, there are of course other fonts that can be used with `fontspec` and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. For these, you could check in the font information for the scripts supported by these fonts.

Comment: Searching for file names _containing_ `t2a` is probably better. At least on MikTeX (so I assume on TeX Live too) this doesn't cover Droid (EDIT: actually it doesn't have an `.fd` file at all, but `.tfm` and `.vf` files).

Comment: Actually, I don’t even know if it is obligatory to put the encoding in the font file name. So, there may be even more fonts, but I don’t know how to efficiently search for these.